# Best (fastest) way to parse (enumerate) an NSMutableArray.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I gotta question.

Suppose you have an array `NSMutableArray myArray;` and it has nome objects.

I can say:

```
for (NSObject* anObject in myArray){
  //bla-bla
}
```

I can also say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count-1; i ++){
  //bla-bla
}
```

1. What is the difference between the 2 approaches?
2. Which way is faster?

Any advice (or link, or tut) is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It depends what you do in the //bla-bla line - if you do a message send to get the object from the array, the fast enumeration case is faster.  See: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/fast-enumeration-clarifications.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions shouldn't be too different, especially not noticeably (with the exception of the second code not iterating over all items). If speed is everything you want, you can enumerate the array concurrently using `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` and passing the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option. However, beside of that, using either of the two versions won't make a difference, so you should use whatever you like more. The first version is certainly less type intensive and also works for the other foundation container types (`NSSet`, `NSCountedSet`, `NSDictionary`)

Comment: I found out that I cannot do a [myArray removeObject....] while enumerating this way. I need to make a reverse enumeration instead, using for (int i = myArray.count-1; i >= 0; i --). Ok, I am done with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this great post right here:

[NSArray enumeration performance examined](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance)

It exactly shows which methods are the fastest, and why.